# Press tab keyboard button Jquery Date picker

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I am using http://jqueryui.com/datepicker/ date picker, When I press tab button it goes to date picker box, when I press it a gain the mouse pointer doesn't move to the next box, what can I do?

Comment: Why would the mouse pointer move?

Comment: Please post some code and/or a demo on jsfiddle

Comment: Working fine for me. Please post code or give fiddle reproducing this behavior.

Answer (score 0):

From the [API Documentation](http://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/):

> ## Keyboard interaction
>
> While the datepicker is open, the following key commands are
> available:
>
> PAGE UP: Move to the previous month.
> PAGE DOWN: Move to the next month.
> CTRL+PAGE UP: Move to the previous year.
> CTRL+PAGE DOWN: Move to the next year.
> CTRL+HOME: Move to the current month. Open the datepicker if closed.
> CTRL+LEFT: Move to the previous day.
> CTRL+RIGHT: Move to the next day.
> CTRL+UP: Move to the previous week.
> CTRL+DOWN: Move the next week.
> ENTER: Select the focused date.
> CTRL+END: Close the datepicker and erase the date.
> ESCAPE: Close the datepicker without selection.

So basically you can use <kbd>tab</kbd> or <kbd>Crtl</kbd> + <kbd>Home</kbd> to open the date picker and then you can use the above commands to navigate and pick dates.

Comment: All these commands work well, but still I cant't move to the next box by using any of them @apaul34208

Comment: @Alaa you will need to edit your question, and provide the specific code your using. I am not sure what you mean by "I cant't move to the next box". Are you using more than one date input?